# Bazel run - passing main arguments

Tags: bazel

I created  an image using  java_image but I would like to pass arguments to   my main function (i.e. String args[]). How can I do that when I use "bazel run name_of_image" command?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`bazel run //your:rule -- arg1 arg2 ... argN`

Everything after `--` is passed to the binary.

Comment: thanks for your response. Does that applicable using java_image? I mean do I need to set anything in the rule itself to support args?

Comment: It's worth noting too this subtlety: the role of a lone `--` is different under `bazel run` than it is under `bazel test`. For bazel test and build everything to the right of `--` is taken as a *target pattern* https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html

Answer (score 3):

When using `java_image`, `bazel run //my_image` will only load the image into the Docker daemon, it won't run it. To run it, you should use:

```
docker run bazel/my_image:my_image [args]
```

Comment: Actually, when I use bazel run it compiles and runs it.

Comment: If it runs the image, it should also use the arguments you specify (as per László's answer). It seems I was confused by a bug: depending on the value of the `base` attribute, `bazel run` may or may not run the Docker image after loading.